# Adding HTML element after the dataset is brought in

Tags: javascript, typeahead, typeahead.js

In [Typeahead JS](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) I'm trying to add an option that appears at the bottom of the dropdown after the user has started typing. Currently I'm using the 'onOpened' [Custom Event](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#custom-events) to trigger adding some HTML after the 'tt-dropdown-menu' element is initialised.

```
.on('typeahead:opened', onOpened)
  function onOpened($e) {
    $('.tt-dropdown-menu').html( "<a href="">Add Option</a>" );
}
```

The problem is that the jQuery HTML is added when the dropdown is initialised, as expected, then when the user starts typing the new dataset element with the autocomplete results in is added below that jQuery HTML so the jQuery HTML can never appear at the bottom of the dropdown. You can't append the jQuery HTML to the dataset either as that element doesn't exist when the dropdown is initialised.

Is there an easier way around this? The other Custom Events don't seem to cover this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one `dataset`, you can do as I do: add a `footer` to the dataset, and add it as a DOM element, not plain HTML string. You can then change it at will (say on any event you wish) and your changes are reflected in the dropdown.

Example:

```
$('#myinput').typeahead({
    // rest of your regular stuff, like 'name', 'remote', etc.
    footer: $('#dropdown-footer'),
});
```

... where `dropdown-footer` is the ID of a `div` you have somewhere in your dom. You can then do things like:

```
$('#dropdown-footer').html('Hello')
```

Comment: Great answer Nitzen, although now there is the problem of keeping the footer there when no autocomplete results are selected, as it disappears when the dataset goes. Without setting a different function for every event. Seems overly complicated.

Comment: @DanChristian: thanks. I actually do something "ugly" to overcome this in my own solution. I add a `filter` function that, if there are no terms matching the query, does two things: (1) returns a single, dummy, entry. (2) adds a "no-results" CSS class on the #input. My CSS rules make it so that a single tt-suggestion, if a child of the #input.no-results-class, is not displayed. The `filter` removes the CSS class if there *are* answers. That way, even when there are no results, I still get an invisible "dummy" result, and my footer is displayed. HTH.

Comment: Damn, really ugly! But that should solve my problem! Thanks. I've added it as an issue on GIT to Typeahead, hopefully get a more elegant solution soon. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't work in my case, maybe because our suggest has multiple sections, but I found another approach, see my answer in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437107/typeahead-js-show-that-there-are-more-results/31787170#31787170