# Typeahead.js footer text at the end of menu

Tags: jquery, footer, typeahead.js

I am using the Typeahead.js library and it works great. I want to show a html content at the end of the drop-down menu. I am aware that there is an option to show a footer for each datalist. I don't want to show the footer for every list.

I want to show a master footer at the end of the drop-down menu. I am using the below code.

```
$("#search-box").bind("typeahead:opened", function(obj, datum) {
     $("div .tt-dataset-last").parent().append("Click Here");
});
```

The above code works, but not for teh first time when the menu opens. It shows from the second time when the menu is opened. I want the text to be displayed even when the menu is shown for the first time.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `$("#search-box").trigger("typeahead:opened")` as a dirty hack?

Comment: Thanks. Where do you want this to be put?

Comment: `.bind('event').trigger('event')`.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit.. i have tried them both and not sure where exactly they need to be placed.

Comment: You *could* add a footer to the final dataset.

Comment: @NitzanShaked : That will not work as it will be displayed only if there is a match for the datums in the final dataset.

Comment: @Purus: well there's an ugly hack that I can think of, but before I even suggest it: is the data source `remote` or otherwise (`local`, `prefetch`)?

Comment: @Purus: one more thing -- why do you `append` to the dropdown every time it is opened? Why not append to it only once, say after creation? You would change your selector, of course, to be `.tt-dropdown-menu`, and append to it only once.

Comment: @NitzanShaked: The source is remote.. all my 15 lists are remote. I tried that and it does not work that way.

Answer (score 2):

Given that all your datasets are remotes, you can use what I suggested here:

[Adding HTML element after the dataset is brought in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109882/adding-html-element-after-the-dataset-is-brought-in)

... do it for your last dataset, and make sure to read the comments I added to the answer as well.

Good luck.

Comment: Looks like you solved the probem. About filter, can I refer to any jsfiddle to understand it better?

Comment: I am using the below code as the last local dummy datum.. Am I doing it correct? What should I send in the filter return data?          {
          name: "footer",
          local: [],
          footer: "<h3 class=\"footer\">More Results..</h3>",
          filter: function(respData) {
             return [{value: "dummy",tokens: ["dummy"]}];
          }

Comment: Wow. It works great. But there is a problem. There is an empty suggestion showing now and when its clicked, the word "dummy" is added to the textbox which does not looks good. I have put .dummy class height as 0, but still does not change..

Comment: also not able to pass the %QUERY to the url I provide in footer link which I want to customize

Comment: I also don't want the text to the added to textbox when an value is selected.. if we do that, the above problem will be solved

Comment: The fiddle I created doesn't show "dummy" for me. Can you post your code? In any case, try adding "overflow: hidden" to the "dummy" class. It's hard to say without looking, it might be something in your html or css. I am not sure I understand your comment re the footer link, can you provide an example?

Comment: Here is the code of last datum. {
    remote: {
        url: "search/get-dummy/",
        filter: function (response) {
            return [{value: "dummy",url:"http://wwww.google.com"}];
        },
    },
    template: "<div class="dummy"></div>",
    engine: Hogan,
    footer: "<div class="footer"><a href="/search/%QUERY">Search Google</a></div>"
}