# Typeahead.js - Show that there are more results

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I am using typeahead.js and everything works fine for me, except one thing:

I display only 5 entries in the suggestion dropdown, but if there are more results, I would like to show the user, that there are more results (but not the results itself, just the info, that there are more results) so that he goes on typing.

- I don't want a scrollbar
- I don't want to show the other results
- Just an info, that there are more results

Please see screen attached.

[image]

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23984949/203371) answer for how to increase the number of suggestions displayed.

Comment: But thats not what I want. I don't want to increase the limit, I want to show that there are more results.

Comment: So I tried to make it more clear, that I don't want to increase the limit or show more results.

Comment: @BenSmith This is not a duplicate. That [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981704/typeahead-always-shows-only-5-suggestions-maximum) is for increasing the maximum number of suggestions shown. The OP's question is about how to show the count how many additional results there are.

Comment: Thank you for reopening it and sorry if first version of my question was maybe unclear. My problem is, that i use 3 different datasources in the autocomplete and so I can't show a scroll bar.

Comment: @BenSmith, yeah, that "23 results" should be clickable - there should be a way to specify a link for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a filter that just pulls out the length.  In this example, only 20 results would be shown but I wanted people to know if there were more results not being displayed. 
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109882/adding-html-element-after-the-dataset-is-brought-in) for putting the results in a footer.

```js
    var addresses = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('number'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 20,
        remote: {
            url: 'url?q=%QUERY',
            filter: function(list) {
                $('#search-total').html(list.length);
                return list;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for exactly the same thing and think, this is what you need (see the comment from jharding on 4 Feb 2014):
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/642#issuecomment-34025203

The example in the link also works for the `footer` template like follows.

You can save the number of results somewhere in the DOM from the `filter` function of the Bloodhound (where you have access to the result of your AJAX request) like this:

```
var bloodHound = new Bloodhound({
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 5,
  remote: {
      url: url+'%QUERY',
      filter: function (srcs) {
        // store field JSON response to the DOM
        $('#num-results').html(srcs.numResults);
        ...
      }
    }
});
bloodHound.initialize();
```

Now the key point from the link above:
You can wrap the Handlebars template (which is actually a function) and extend/replace the Handlebars context passed to the template this way:

```
var footerTmpl = Handlebars.compile('{{numResults}} results for {{query}}');

var footer = function(context) {
  var numResults = $('#num-results').html();
  var data = { 'numResults': numResults, 'query': context.query };
  return footerTmpl(data);
}

// ...
templates: {
  footer: footer
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might actually be from [bloodhound](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/dist/bloodhound.js) on line `596`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typeahead.js has a footer template. The documentation for this states:

> footer – Rendered at the bottom of the dataset. Can be either a HTML
>   string or a precompiled template. If it's a precompiled template, the
>   passed in context will contain query and isEmpty.

Hence this will *not* allow you to send in a suggestion object as the context, which you could have used for reporting on the search count (i.e. "23 results" message in your example). It only makes use of the query and isEmpty e.g.

```
footer: Handlebars.compile("<b>Searched for '{{query}}'</b>")
```

An example of typeahead.js using the Handlebars template engine can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/d7jdp03d/

Comment: Thank you for that, I know that there is a footer template and I tried it already, but since it has no informations about the results, it doesn't not solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm just stating that Typeahead does not allow you to do what you want, as it only gets passed the query context. Hope you find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing and came across your question. I finally figured it out for me, so hopefully this will help. For context, this is a Backbone/Marionette application, so my solution might be a little specific for how it's set up. The results count is displayed in the `header` template defined `jQuery#typeahead(options, [*datasets])`, which is called on my input element (where the user types in their search query).

Within the initialization of a `new Bloodhound` which happens in a function `source`, I set the results count within a filter option. I save it to a variable on my ItemView. I sort of hacked `this` (the Marionette.ItemView) by saving it to a variable `self` in the beginning. Be sure to `return results`.

```
source: function () {
  var self = this;
   return new Bloodhound({
   datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
   queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
   remote: {
    url: 'my/search/endpoint',
    filter: function (results) {
      self.resultsCount = results.length;
      return results;
    }
  }
 })
}
```

This function `source` is called in within the typeahead call:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  minLength: 3,
  highlight: true
},
{
  name: 'my-dataset',
  source: this.source(),
  templates: {
    header: require('my/header_template'),
    empty: require('my/empty_template'),
    suggestion: require('my/suggestion_template')
  }
});
```

This happens in the `onRender` of the Marionette.ItemView, where I can then insert the value of `this.resultsCount` into a DOM element that's in the header template. You can tap into the `typeahead:render` event. Here I basically check to see that my DOM element that's going to store the count is there, and I display the total count minus the number of items displayed in `tt-menu` (I just count how many `tt-suggestion` are on the page). I hide the "more" link until there are more to show by clicking through.

```
$('.search-input').on('typeahead:render', function (ev, suggestions, flag, dataset) {
  if ($('.num-results').length) {
    var moreCount = this.resultsCount - $('.tt-suggestion').length;

    $('.num-results').text(moreCount);
    if (moreCount > 0) {
      $('.more').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('.more').addClass('hidden');
    }
  }
}.bind(this))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its an old question but it took me a lot of time to figure out simple thing like that. here is my attempt

initilize a global varible

```
var totalSearchResults;
```

and then add filter and update global variable.

```
   var engine = new Bloodhound({
    remote: {
        url: '/search?q=%QUERY%',
        wildcard: '%QUERY%',
        filter: function (list) {
            window.totalSearchResults = list.length;
            return list;
        }
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('title'),
});
```

init typhead

```
$('#demo-input').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1,
    limit: 6,
}, {
    templates: {
        suggestion: suggestion_template,
        footer: footer_template,
    }
});
```

show results in footer template like that

```
   var footer_template = function (context) {
    return '<div class="suggestion-footer"><a href="/search?q=' + context.query + '">View All ('+window.totalSearchResults+') Results </a></div>';
};
```