# jQuery Count/Length Typeahead Remote

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I have a textbox where I am using auto-complete via [Twitter Typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/), specifically the remote example.

Here is my code:

```
var states = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('state'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: getStateUrl + "?query=%QUERY",
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});

var sLength = states.length; // this comes back as undefined

$('#StateName').typeahead({
    highlight: true
}, {
    name: 'states',
    display: 'state',
    source: states,
    limit: 10
}).bind('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
    $("#StateId").val(suggestion.id);
});
```

If you did not see the comment in my code, `states.length` returns as `undefined`.  I have tried `states.index.datums.length` but that too comes back as `undefined`.

How do I get the `length` or `count` of `states` using the remote twitter typeahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sai-nihar-nightraiser said, you're trying to set the length of results before results have been gathered.
Try it like this:

```
var sLength;

var states = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('state'),
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
remote: {
    url: getStateUrl + "?query=%QUERY",
    wildcard: '%QUERY',
    filter: function (statesResults){
        window.sLength = statesResults.length;
        return statesResults;
  }
});
```

sLength should be equal to the number of states returned after typeahead is run.
I got the info from this post:
[Typeahead.js - Show that there are more results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437107/typeahead-js-show-that-there-are-more-results)

Answer (score 1):

That is because I guess your state.length is getting executed before the API call . Never implemented bloodhound though! Just guessing coz it happens in jQuery ajax requests we will have to handle the outputs data in the call back function when accessed out of it it returns undefined.